# functions to write event handler functions in JS

Tags: javascript, html, events

writing a drag and drop program in html5. when elements are dragged from src and dropped to target, a copy of new element is added to target as child. this newly added ele is suppoed to be movable to i need to add drag events for it. i thot of writing a funciton which takes ele id and operation type as paramenters. this fucntion will be called when a new element is added( dropped to target). this does not seem to be working for me.

Function for dynamically added src element:

```
function dragsrc(ele, op) {
     var dragstartfunc = ele.id + "dragStart";
     var dragendfunc = ele.id + "dragEnd";
     LOG(dragstartfunc);
     LOG(dragendfunc);
     ele.addEventListener('dragstart', dragstartfunc, false);
     ele.addEventListener('dragend', dragendfunc, false);
     window[dragstartfunc] = function(event) {
         LOG(dragstartfunc);
         event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', ele.type);
         event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = op;
     };
     window[dragendfunc] = function(event) {
         LOG(dragendfunc);
     };
 }
```

fucntion for dynamically added target element:

```
function dragtarget(ele, op) {
     var dragenterfunc = ele.id + "dragEnter";
     var dragoverfunc = ele.id + "dragOver";
     var dragleavefunc = ele.id + "dragLeave";
     var dropfunc = ele.id + "drop";
     LOG(dragenterfunc);
     LOG(dragoverfunc);
     LOG(dragleavefunc);
     LOG(dropfunc);
     ele.addEventListener('dragenter', dragenterfunc, false);
     ele.addEventListener('dragover', dragoverfunc, false);
     ele.addEventListener('dragleave', dragleavefunc, false);
     ele.addEventListener('drop', dropfunc, false);
     /* Drop target event handlers */
     window[dragenterfunc] = function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
     };
     window[dragoverfunc] = function(event) {
         event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = op;
         LOG(" :" + event.clientX + " and :" + (240 - event.clientX));
         LOG(":" + event.clientY + " andy :" + (100 - event.clientY));
         event.preventDefault();
         return true;
     };
     window[dragleavefunc] = function(event) {};
     window[dropfunc] = function(event) {
         LOG(" :" + event.clientX + " and :" + (240 - event.clientX));
         LOG(":" + event.clientY + " andy :" + (100 - event.clientY));
         var data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
         var ele = createinputele(data);
         var eletext = createinputele("text");
         var img = createimg("./labeledit.gif", "edit");
         event.target.appendChild(eletext);
         event.target.appendChild(img);
         event.target.appendChild(ele);
         return true;
     };
 }
```

if i call these function manully( passing dummy event parametr) it does not throw any 'undefined' error, that means fucntions are defined but its not being picked by the event listener. coz whenever any src is dragged its dragstart fucntion is not called( i dont see the log note LOG is defined).
am i trying to achieve possible thing?

Comment: you confuse some strings with functions. `addEventListener()` expects a function as the second argument, you pass it some property-name instead. check `LOG(typeof dragenterfunc)`. And why do you think you need to register all these functions in the global namespace?

Comment: I added it to global namespace because it the function( handles) will be used by eventmanager even after the execution of this function.( i am new to Javascript so please tolerate my stupid Qs).

Comment: I don't know your eventmanager, but it should organize it's data on it's own. If the eventmanager is somehow involves in this you should call it and pass the functions it needs, instead of polluting the global namespace. Maybe that's the topic for another Question!?

Comment: by event manager i meant eventlsitener and all. BTW how can i convert it into a function. even after fucntion definition type remains same.

Comment: Just removed the window[] and assignd funtion definition to the variable, which converts it to a function then add event by addEventListener.